# Why getting this error for Laravel JWT auth on heroku server

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt

Getting this error when calling any api:

`Argument 3 passed to Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\Hmac::doVerify() must be an instance of Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\Key, null given, called in /app/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/BaseSigner.php on line 44`

I am using `tymondesigns/jwt-auth` with laravel for api authentication.
I tried running this `php artisan optimize` after generating `jwt:secret`

My laravel application is hosted on basic heroku server with pgsql

Comment: `php artisan config:clear` then cache again `php artisan config:cache` hope the error has gone ? if not then set a key by `php artisan jwt:secret`

Comment: not working, same error

Comment: clear your config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that you are getting this error when you uploaded the applications before implementing the `JWT` and re-uploaded directly without reuploading the `.env` file.

If this is the case, the simplest way to solve this adding the JWT key in your `.env` file :

Here an example:

```
JWT_SECRET=jghgvfuldMpw5i4039393939393372y98bEWumqd9ls7Uk8DEpr0gIhgftrf
```

Or create `jwt` key with the command :

```
php artisan jwt:secret
```

Don't forget to clear config after changing your environment  :

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: adding `JWT_SECRET=some_secret` to heroku config vars solved the issue.